# Is it possible to retrieve labels in a managed package from the flow builder?

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, label, builder

I would like to use labels from a managed package in the flow builder but it seems there is no way to do so. Is this the case or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can.
Just need to manually add the package namespace to the label, because seems SF doesn't add it when you select the label:

{!$Label.pknamespace__packageLabel}

Comment: Is that a double underscore between the package namespace and the package label? It is not working.

Comment: Yes. double. It is working for me. Maybe you are not using the correct namespace